# Direction of apostrophe in Hawai'i

Tags: punctuation, cultural-correctness

My students are writing a case study about Hawai'i and we'd like to use the diacritical mark, correctly. My searches so far are turning up both

> Hawai’i
>   and
>   Hawai‘i

Can anyone tell me a preferred form - should the apostrophe be "closing" as in the first form, or "open" as in the second form?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't an apostrophe: it is a distinct mark (letter, in Hawaiian) called *ʻokina*. In Unicode it is U+02BB ʻ MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA

It resembles a left (or opening) quotation mark - your second option. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOkina) discusses the different ways it has been represented where the system or font lacks it.

Comment: Can you summarize what the WP article says are the alternatives? (to make this answer self-contained)

Comment: I realized after I posted that the Hawaii state government website would have been a good place to look too (and agrees with your answer). https://portal.ehawaii.gov/ Thank you very much!